# Elasticsearch Php Date mapping, filtering and searching

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Please help me. I am using php 5.5 and Elasticsearch 2.1. I want to do ranking among history. But my date filter does not work correctly.

I am getting accurate results when I made query only between the dates.However, I am not getting accurate results when I made query with date mont, day and hour.

**For example :**

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017/12/3123:59:59&my_date_gte=2016/01/0100:00:00

**Result is not correct.**

**Example 2:**

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017&my_date_gte=2016

**Result is correct.**

**My date mapping :**

```
$myTypeMapping['properties']['my_date']['type']='date';    
$myTypeMapping['properties']['my_date']['index']='not_analyzed';    
$myTypeMapping['properties']['my_date']['format']='yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss';
```

**My date filter :**

```
 unset($filter_my_date);    

 if(isset($_GET[my_date_try])){    
     $filter_my_date['range']['my_date']['lte']=$_GET['my_date_lte'];    
     $filter_my_date['range']['my_date']['gte']=$_GET['my_date_gte'];    
     $filter_my_date['range']['my_date']['format']='yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss';
 }

 if(is_array($filter_my_date)){    
      $searchParams['body']['query']['bool']['must']=$filter_my_date;    
 }
```

**What is the problem?**

Answer (score 0):

Your format string has a space between day and hour, your example URL has not:

```
$myTypeMapping['properties']['my_date']['format']='yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss';
                                                             ^

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017/12/3123:59:59&my_date_gte=2016/01/0100:00:00
                                                                   ^                              ^
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it:

**example 1:**

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017/12/31 23:59:59&my_date_gte=2016/01/01 00:00:00

**example 2:**

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017&my_date_gte=2016

**example 3 :Also I wrote only the date without time:**

http://10.0.2.15:8080/filter.php?my_date_try&my_date_lte=2017/12/31 &my_date_gte=2016/01/01

The second example, the result is correct, but the others are wrong